# Is it appropriate to perform ANOVA's on cluster group variable

Tags: anova, clustering

I have completed 2-step cluster analysis on a data set and the result is that I have 4 cluster groups. The groups cluster around wellbeing variables - e.g positive affect, carefreeness etc. The cluster output provides box plots indicating the median scores for each variable within each of the 4 clusters.The output also provides mean scores. Is it now appropriate to conduct ANOVA's on each of the cluster group mean scores for wellbeing variables to determine if the differences between the 4 groups on the variables are significant? Or is the fact that the algorithm has created the clusters sufficient analysis?

Comment: Cluster analysis will _always_ produce groups that are statistically significant (unless the sample size is very small). You may apply univariate ANOVA to clustering results only as a tool to see what the features used contributed and what didn't, to the separation on the clusters. You may use ANOVA also to see if the features that did not participate in clustering has something to do with the cluster differences. You should mind also overfitting problem of a single-sample cluster analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your response - very helpful.